# Python3 and 'code' CLI not working after updating to MacOS Monterey

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-monterey

I updated to MacOS Monterey and now python is not working:

```
➜  ~ python3 --version    
dyld[6578]: dyld cache '/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
dyld[6578]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file)
[1]    6578 abort      python3 --version
```

But if I run:

```
➜  ~ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
```

I am able to run it. But when running `code .` for opening a project in vs code it gives the same error:

```
dyld[6683]: dyld cache '/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
dyld[6683]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file)
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what to do so that it runs commands like `code .` successfully.

Comment: Seems like both the `python` and `code` commands aren't in your PATH anymore.

Comment: @BjornB. That's not what the error says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your python3 is 3.8.9 but the error message is for 3.6. It looks like you have clashing python versions. I fixed this error on my machine by uninstalling 3.6 and all of its syslinks like seen [here](https://www.techjunkie.com/macos-uninstall-python3/) under "Uninstalling Python 3 Using Terminal", except I used homebrew commands `brew doctor` and then `brew cleanup` for steps 4. and 5.

Comment: Removing things from `/Library/Frameworks` will probably cause more issues somewhere else, though and unclear how that fixes `./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

This is 100% a version conflict/PATH problem.

First, open up terminal and try running `echo $PATH`. It should print something like this:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

As you can see, it says **3.10** for me, while yours says **3.6**

@guest_fish makes a good suggestion with deleting outdated versions of Python, but another way you can try is by checking the following:

- `vim $HOME/.zprofile` ---> this is the zsh analogue to .bash_profile, here's what mine looks like:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.10
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Note how it matches the first part of the path I `echo`'d above

- `vim /etc/paths` ---> this should match the middle parts of your `PATH`, mine looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

- `vim /etc/paths.d/<your_unique_id>` (just press tab to complete it when you're in paths.d, you generally have only one option). Mine looks like this:

`/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

Note how it matches the end of the path

*When you visit each of these files, you can modify them (password protected obv) to put `/usr/bin/python3`  first, meaning that will be the first place that it looks for python build files and will (hopefully) use the correct version*

---

Now, to fix the `code` thing, you could try going into VSCode and hitting `SHIFT + ⌘ + P`, then select **Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH** - this should update it for you automatically.

Lmk how it goes!

Comment: I tried adding the python 3 path in those files but I still get the same error.

Comment: When running echo $PATH I get - ```/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin:/usr/bin/python3:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin```

Comment: i've been searching everywhere.... this seems to be the only helpful answer.. I was able to insert '/usr/bin/python3' into all 3 of the files (the last two files needed sudo to edit in vim, but the error still persists when trying to run dev_appserver.py.... 'no such file or directory'